# Alamofire refreshToken with Retrier: how to get status of refreshToken request and reroute to LoginView

Tags: swift, alamofire

I customize refreshTokens functions according to Alamofire [guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests).

I'd like to reroute to Login View when refreshTokens failed and got 401 status from API server (for other error status like 400 or 500, just display error message in the view).
Currently I use UserDefaults to notice 401 status to the view (, who call the Alamofire request).

I'd like to know if there's better approach to notice "refreshToken status" to the view (or approach to share the status variable with view and oauth2handler).

thanks!

- OAuth2Handler

  ```
      manager.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
          .responseJSON { [weak self] response in
              guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

              if
                  let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                  let accessToken = json["access_token"] as? String
              {
                  completion(true, accessToken)
              } else {
                  if let status = response.response?.statusCode, status == 401 {
                      UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "login_required")

                  }
                  completion(false, nil)
              }

              strongSelf.isRefreshing = false
      }
  ```
- ViewController action when some button clicked

  ```
  _ = client.request(API.addLike(json: comment))
      .subscribe(
          onSuccess: { (response) in
              // successful!
          },
          onError: { (err) in
              let loginRequired = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "login_required")
              if loginRequired == true {
                  print("refresh token is wrong or expired. login required")
                  // transition to LoginView
              } else {
                  print("request is invalid or server is down.")
              }
          }
      )
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently managed the same situation for one of my app. I have created an `OAuthManager` class which inherits from `RequestAdapter` and `RequestRetrier`.

In the `func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest`, I adapt my request with my `Authorization` token.

In `func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion)` I am checking the result of the request before sending to the completion handler of Alamofire.

In my case, I can receive 401 error code for expired access tokens or simply because the user is not authorized to perform this action. So, I am checking the server message sent by my REST API in order to be sure that the access token is expired and request a new one.

If the refresh token API returns an error, I display the LoginViewController directly from the `should` function by doing:

```
let rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WELCOME_NAVIGATION")
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootViewController
```

I can do this because my login methods are available from an `UIViewController`. If you want to use an `UIView`, you can maybe add a subview to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController.view`.

If you want to display a notification or something like this, maybe it will be better to use `NotificationCenter` to trigger some code in your `UIView`.

Regards,

IMACODE